# Mouse settings reset on reboot

Tags: windows-10, mouse

I have a Windows 10 machine (v. 1803). A minor annoyance is the fact that recently, although I can't pinpoint the exact time, I loose my specific Microsoft Wireless Mobile 4000 mouse settings (extra mouse button functions, scroll wheel speed) on reboot.

If I start the 'Microsoft mouse and keyboard center', my customized settings are reinstated. I could auto start it everytime, but that is one more window opening on reboot (and not very elegant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that there is an entry for 'Microsoft mouse and keyboard center' in the startup but it is not visible by using Task Manager -> Startup.

By using a more powerful tool such as [Autoruns for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) from Sysinternals, one can see 'Microsoft mouse and keyboard center' and enable it.